# uninstal package using adb

Tags: android, adb

I have a problem with "Whatsapp" application I deleted It a year before and now when I am trying to install It It says "are u sure to update this app" so It's recognized as installed app! although this failed to install/update this version.
I am using "adb" to check if it is install using:

```
>> adb shell pm list packages com.whatsapp
```

I couldn't get any result, but If I used dubpsys:

```
>> adb shell dumpsys package com.whatsapp
Key Set Manager:
  [com.whatsapp]
      Signing KeySets: 4

Packages:
  Package [com.whatsapp] (855db2e):
    userId=10294
    pkg=null
    codePath=/data/app/com.whatsapp-i5kfQuE4DBbdia3d_Va_IA==
    resourcePath=/data/app/com.whatsapp-i5kfQuE4DBbdia3d_Va_IA==
    legacyNativeLibraryDir=/data/app/com.whatsapp-i5kfQuE4DBbdia3d_Va_IA==/lib
    primaryCpuAbi=armeabi-v7a
    secondaryCpuAbi=null
    versionCode=4453427
    timeStamp=٢٠٢٠-١٠-١١ ١١:٣٠:٠٧
    firstInstallTime=٢٠٢٠-١٠-١١ ١١:٣٠:١٠
    lastUpdateTime=٢٠٢٠-١٠-١١ ١١:٣٠:١٠
    installerPackageName=com.google.android.packageinstaller
    signatures=PackageSignatures{8831c94 version:3, signatures:[d7f1f224], past signatures:[]}
    installPermissionsFixed=true
    pkgFlags=[ ]
    install permissions:
      com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE: granted=true
      android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS: granted=true
      android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS: granted=true
      com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES: granted=true
      android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS: granted=true
      android.permission.NFC: granted=true
      android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE: granted=true
      android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE: granted=true
      android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS: granted=true
      android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED: granted=true
      com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT: granted=true
      android.permission.READ_PROFILE: granted=true
      android.permission.BLUETOOTH: granted=true
      android.permission.GET_TASKS: granted=true
      android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS: granted=true
      android.permission.INTERNET: granted=true
      android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT: granted=true
      android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY: granted=true
      com.whatsapp.permission.REGISTRATION: granted=true
      android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE: granted=true
      android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE: granted=true
      android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT: granted=true
      android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS: granted=true
      android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS: granted=true
      android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS: granted=true
      com.whatsapp.sticker.READ: granted=true
      android.permission.VIBRATE: granted=true
      android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE: granted=true
      android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC: granted=true
      com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT: granted=true
      android.permission.WAKE_LOCK: granted=true
    User 0: ceDataInode=0 installed=true hidden=false suspended=false stopped=true notLaunched=true enabled=0 instant=false virtual=false
      gids=[3002, 3003]
      runtime permissions:
        android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG: granted=false, flags=[ USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_GRANTED|USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_DENIED|RESTRICTION_INSTALLER_EXEMPT|RESTRICTION_UPGRADE_EXEMPT]
        android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: granted=false, flags=[ USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_GRANTED|USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_DENIED]
        android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS: granted=true, flags=[ USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_GRANTED|USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_DENIED]
        android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS: granted=true, flags=[ USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_GRANTED|USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_DENIED|RESTRICTION_INSTALLER_EXEMPT|RESTRICTION_UPGRADE_EXEMPT]
        android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: granted=true, flags=[ USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_GRANTED|USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_DENIED|RESTRICTION_INSTALLER_EXEMPT|RESTRICTION_UPGRADE_EXEMPT]
        android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION: granted=false, flags=[ USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_GRANTED|USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_DENIED]
        android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE: granted=true, flags=[ USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_GRANTED|USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_DENIED]
        android.permission.SEND_SMS: granted=true, flags=[ USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_GRANTED|USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_DENIED|RESTRICTION_INSTALLER_EXEMPT|RESTRICTION_UPGRADE_EXEMPT]
        android.permission.CALL_PHONE: granted=true, flags=[ USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_GRANTED|USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_DENIED]
        android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS: granted=true, flags=[ USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_GRANTED|USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_DENIED]
        android.permission.CAMERA: granted=true, flags=[ USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_GRANTED|USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_DENIED]
        android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS: granted=true, flags=[ USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_GRANTED|USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_DENIED]
        android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: granted=true, flags=[ USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_GRANTED|USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_DENIED|RESTRICTION_INSTALLER_EXEMPT|RESTRICTION_UPGRADE_EXEMPT]
        android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO: granted=true, flags=[ USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_GRANTED|USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_DENIED]
        android.permission.READ_CONTACTS: granted=true, flags=[ USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_GRANTED|USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_DENIED]
    User 10: ceDataInode=0 installed=false hidden=false suspended=false stopped=true notLaunched=true enabled=0 instant=false virtual=false
      gids=[3002, 3003]
      runtime permissions:
        android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG: granted=false, flags=[ APPLY_RESTRICTION]
        android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS: granted=false, flags=[ APPLY_RESTRICTION]
        android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: granted=false, flags=[ APPLY_RESTRICTION]
        android.permission.SEND_SMS: granted=false, flags=[ APPLY_RESTRICTION]
        android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: granted=false, flags=[ APPLY_RESTRICTION]

Package Changes:
  Sequence number=38
  User 0:
    seq=17, package=com.jb.emoji.gokeyboard
    seq=19, package=com.android.vending
    seq=23, package=com.google.android.apps.docs
    seq=30, package=com.huawei.health
    seq=32, package=com.google.android.gms
    seq=33, package=com.file.manager.filebrowser
    seq=35, package=eu.thedarken.sdm
    seq=37, package=pl.solidexplorer2



Compiler stats:
  Unable to find package: com.whatsapp

Active APEX packages:


Inactive APEX packages:


Factory APEX packages:


  APEX session state:
```

I tried to uninstall It using  adb but it failed due internal error:

```
>>adb uninstall com.whatsapp
Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]
>>db uninstall -k com.whatsapp
The -k option uninstalls the application while retaining the data/cache.
At the moment, there is no way to remove the remaining data.
You will have to reinstall the application with the same signature, and fully uninstall it.
If you truly wish to continue, execute 'adb shell cmd package uninstall -k'.
>>adb shell cmd package uninstall -k com.whatsapp
Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]
>>adb uninstall --user 0 com.whatsapp
Failure [not installed for 0]
```

finally I tried to install It using adb I get this:

```
>>adb install -r ww.apk
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install ww.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.whatsapp signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!]
```

I tried deleting cache from mobile, google play and google service but It is the same, any idea how I can uninstall this package using adb?

Comment: `Package com.whatsapp signatures do not match previously installed version` means that you can not install a modified version of Whatsapp without deleting your user data. First fully uninstall Whatsapp including user data then install the modified Whatsapp version.

Comment: @Robert any Idea how can I delete user data? would that affect other applications?

Answer (score 0):

try using: `adb shell` then
 `pm uninstall -k package-name` to remove the app leaving cache and data and
this: `pm uninstall package-name` to remove everything.
you should see `success` at end.

Comment: I mentioned that in the description and It failed can check It again

Comment: ```
>>pm uninstall -k com.whatsapp
Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]
```